# Evitemos que se pueda volver a publicar la misma pregunta después de borrarla

Tags: característica-nueva, preguntas, eliminación-de-preguntas

Me disculpo de antemano si no es una buena pregunta pero tengo varios días con esta inquietud...

> He notado como se está haciendo costumbre en StackOverflow que los
>   usuarios **OP**  al observar que su respuesta no obtuvo la suficiente
>   atención, borren la pregunta y la suban nuevamente.

Verdaderamente desconozco si esto es una acción normal o permitida en este sitio, sin embargo, considero que aquellas preguntas eliminadas y publicadas nuevamente generan disconformidad en los usuarios que intentamos colaborar en su solución ya que en muchas de estás preguntas eliminadas la solución ya ha sido planteada a través de nuestros comentarios y respuestas. Es por ello que no tiene sentido eliminarla para volverla a publicar ya que si se cuenta con la respuesta no hay motivo justificable para que sea eliminada.

He observado que esta situación se presenta principalmente porque es muy sencillo para un **OP** el proceso de eliminar la pregunta y al necesitar que su pregunta sea resuelta en la brevedad posible o que un tercer usuario le explique mejor lo que no entendió en un comentario o respuesta de un segundo usuario, el **OP** termina tomando la decisión de eliminar y volver a crear la pregunta ya que así más usuarios prestarán atención a la pregunta (por estar 2 veces la pregunta en primera página imagino)

> **Solución:** planteo que para eliminar la pregunta el **OP** tenga ciertas restricciones, limitaciones o reglas. Por ejemplo que el
>   usuario una vez cree la pregunta está tenga un tiempo de vida minimo
>   de 2 semanas y que si se desea eliminar antes de este tiempo se
>   consulte un moderador para que este apruebe o desapruebe la
>   eliminación de la misma.

Repito nuevamente, no sé si el proceso de eliminar y montar nuevamente la pregunta a cada momento sea algo aprobado en este sitio pero sí hago publica mi incomodidad ante esta situación. Esta semana he visto no menos de 5 preguntas re posteadas y una de ellas de hecho tenía la solución en uno de los comentarios (yo mismo realicé el proceso descrito en el comentario y daba solución a la pregunta realizada).

Espero puedan aclararme si El proceso descrito aquí es normal para esta comunidad. Soy un usuario que ha crecido con Stack Overflow y me ha sido tan útil para solucionar mis dudas que intento (aparte de participar constantemente en la solución de las dudas de otros colegas) aportar aunque sea muy poco en el mantenimiento y la mejora del sitio.

> ***Observación:*** Las preguntas que he visto re posteadas han tenido exactamente el mismo titulo y descripción por lo que el único motivo
>   aparente para que esta conducta suceda es para conseguir las vistas
>   necesarias como para que la inquietud sea resuelta casi
>   inmediatamente.

Comment: Para eso ya tenemos la moderación. No estoy de acuerdo en que un usuario no tenga "derecho" a eliminar su pregunta. Puede darse el caso de que sea una pregunta de muy baja calidad, y tras algun comentario o votos el OP decida eliminarla. Se corre el riesgo de que hagan lo que dices, volver a crearla, pero en el proceso de moderación si sigue siendo de baja calidad terminará siendo cerrada.

Comment: Las restricciones de eliminación de preguntas son principalmente para las de buena calidad. Es raro que una pregunta que tenga que ser borrada y publicada de nuevo, sea todo lo buena que necesita ser.  Si detectas este comportamiento, pulsa en `"se necesita la intervecion de un moderador"` para hacer lo propio con la publicación y hablar con el usuario. Un saludo

Comment: Ok. Gracias @Pikoh tienes razón no lo había analizado de esa forma.

Comment: @lois6b Gracias ya por lo menos conozco que debo hacer cuando suceda este tipo de casos. Mi preocupación era porque en menos de 1 semana he visto 5 preguntas distintas que han sido eliminadas y publicadas nuevamente y considero que es bastante dado que en la primera página de SOes sólo aparecen 15 entonces se le resta la oportunidad a preguntas nuevas por volver a ver preguntas que ya en muchos de los casos fueron respondidas e igual se eliminaron para volver a publicarse.

Comment: Pero tomaré en cuenta lo que me recomiendas @lois6b y cuando vea la pregunta publicada nuevamente marco "se necesita la intervención de un moderador" y listo. Gracias nuevamente por tu solución

Comment: Y lo que hacen además es porque no saben que al editar una publicidad, sube en la sección de preguntas recientes

Comment: @lois6b Toda la razón ni yo que ya tengo 4 meses aquí tenía conocimiento (o no me había dado cuenta aún) que las publicaciones subian de puesto al ser editadas. Pensé que al realizar una pregunta y no era solucionada en el tiempo en que podía generar más vistas (cuando está publicada en primera página) ya no había forma de revivirla salvo generando una "bounty" o recompensa por ella. Pero gracias a tu aclaratoria veo que si existe otra alternativa (editarla con el propósito de que mejore la pregunta y suba en la sección de preguntas para tener la posibilidad nuevamente de ser resuelta).

Comment: Nuevamente gracias por la aclaratoria @lois6b

Comment: @Huskie por supuesto el edit tiene que ser válido. También se siguen usuarios que editan publicaciones pero no mejoran nada por si hacen mal uso y solo ganar visibilidad

Comment: @Pikoh claro es como dices si la pregunta no es de calidad será reportada y eliminada como lo garantiza la moderación pero que pasa si es buena y aún así el OP la borra "sin una razón lógica aparente"? Era por eso mi recomendación ya que si se evita eliminar con un tiempo mínimo de vida obligatorio se garantiza que los usuarios no esten re publicando preguntas sólo por "urgencia" además que los usuarios "no tan nuevos" pero nuevos al fín se preocuparán por redactar y describir mejor la pregunta ya que tendrán conocimiento de que no puede ser eliminada por un tiempo.

Comment: @lois6b Sí, eso si lo sabía porque me lo aclararon en otra pregunta que hice aquí en meta pero es bueno recalcarlo así los demás usuarios que no sepan se enteran también al leer esta pregunta

Comment: Bueno,cada uno es libre de eliminar su publicación si esta no tiene respuestas. Si la pregunta es buena y ya ha obtenido alguna respuesta (con al menos un voto), ésta no se puede eliminar, como está explicado en en [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Comment: @Pikoh Entiendo. Ya no me quedan dudas. Es que si ya no existía algo como lo que proponía yo en SOes era seguro porque ya se había pensado y descartado por alguna razón importante. Pasaba que no entendía cual era la razón de porque no se había implementado algo como mi propuesta pero ahora me queda claro. Muchas gracias por explicarme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como han indicado otros usuarios en los comentarios, no se puede restringir el derecho a un usuario a eliminar su pregunta si no recibe ninguna respuesta ya que va contra las reglas de la pagina; como indica el centro de ayuda en [¿Por qué y cómo algunas preguntas son eliminadas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Los usuarios pueden eliminar sus propias preguntas si la pregunta:

- Tiene cero respuestas
- Una sola respuesta, pero esa respuesta no tiene votos a favor

Como indicas hay usuarios que eliminan sus preguntas para volver a subirlas a la pagina con el fin de que estén arriba en la cola de preguntas y tengan otra oportunidad de ser respondidas.

El sistema cuenta con un mecanismo de defensa ante estos comportamientos; cuando un usuario ha publicado varias preguntas que no fueron bien recibidas por la comunidad, este restringe la publicación de preguntas de dicho usuario por un día o mas como indica el centro de ayuda en [¿Por qué el sistema me esta pidiendo esperar un día o más antes de hacer otra pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited). Por tanto si las preguntas son realmente malas, reportalas como preguntas de muy baja calidad y espera a que el sistema se encargue.

De igual forma los usuarios pueden editar su pregunta consecutivamente para que esta este arriba en la cola de preguntas en lugar de eliminarla, de hecho esto se recomienda en [¿Qué debo hacer si nadie contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Y también en caso de ver estos comportamientos puedes reportar la pregunta a un moderador (reportar->se necesita la intervención de un moderador y dar una breve explicación) <strike>o ser indiferente a estas preguntas y esperar a que dicho usuario se canse</strike>.

Espero haber resuelto tus dudas y no temas dar a conocer las preguntas que tengas que para eso es la pagina. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente aporte. Muchas gracias por la informacion!